# How can I run two different tasks in pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telebot

I want to run two different tasks in pyTelegramBotAPI. But the task after the bot run task is not running.

```
import telebot, asyncio, datetime

bot = telebot.Telebot(token)

def task1():
    bot.polling()

def task2():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 12 and now.minute == 30:
        bot.send_document(admin_id, open("work_db.db", "rb"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(task1) # This task is running
    asyncio.create_task(task2()) # This is not working
```

After the bot runs, subsequent tasks do not run.

Comment: Your functions task1 and task2 are not asyncio tasks, because they (1) are not declared async def, and (2) do not contain await expressions.  Even if you fixed that, your call to asyncio.run() will execute task1 to completion before proceeding.  You should perhaps look at an asyncio tutorial to see how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark functions with async `async def task1():`
2. Create main async function and start tasks in it

```py
import telebot, asyncio, datetime

bot = telebot.Telebot(token)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*(task1(), task2())) # You can optionally add return_exceptions=True

async def task1():
    bot.polling()

async def task2():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 12 and now.minute == 30:
        bot.send_document(admin_id, open("work_db.db", "rb"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I did as you said, the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry, found my error, now it's fixed

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't happen again. task1() works but task2() does not.

Comment: Are you sure that your second task do something? add print at the start of task1 and task2 and check if they are called, if they print, so it's problem in something else

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, it doesn't switch to task2() after task1()

Comment: What do you need actually? I already answered how to run 2 tasks, 2 tasks in parallel, and how to just run tasks, I just don't understand what you need

Comment: Your two tasks will not cooperatively multitask because neither one contains an await expression.  Just putting async in front of the function definition does not cause it to yield control to the event loop.  Only an await expression does that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to post instead of commenting on your post, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Your code has a mistake in task2, it only checks once and (I assume) you want it to check indefinitely.

This is the code you should write instead:

```
async def task2():
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 12 and now.minute == 30:
        bot.send_document(admin_id, open("work_db.db", "rb"))
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

This code checks the time every minute, but you can tweak it to check less times and/or to be more precise. With this function, Kalosst0's answer should work.